# Casting function pointer arguments without a helper function

Tags: c, function, casting, function-pointers

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))
```

Is there a way to pass, let's say `strcmp` to `qsort` without making a helper function?

I was trying to do:

```
qsort(..., (int (*) (const void*, const void*) (strcmp)));
```

Comment: One major problem about not using correctly written helper functions is that `qsort` passes pointers to elements using the pointer-to operator `&`. So if you have an array of pointers the `qsort` function will pass pointer to pointers. And if you have an array or arrays then `qsort` will pass pointers to the arrays which will have the wrong type. So the result really depends on the data you want sorted.

Comment: Also casting between different function pointer types is by no means _guaranteed_ to work. It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt at the cast simply has a misplaced right (closing) parenthesis. The one at the end should be after the *type* of the cast. So, you can change:

```c
(int (*) (const void*, const void*) (strcmp))
//                                          ^ wrong
```

to

```c
(int (*) (const void*, const void*)) (strcmp)
//                                 ^ right
```

Alternatively, although hiding pointer types in `typedef` aliases is severely frowned-upon, *function pointer* types are an exception to that guideline. So, it is easier/clearer to define the required type for the `qsort` comparator first:

```c
typedef int (*QfnCast) (const void*, const void*);
```

Then, you can cast to that type:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*QfnCast) (const void*, const void*);

int main(void)
{
    char list[5][8] = {
        "Fred",
        "Bob",
        "Anna",
        "Gareth",
        "Joe"
    };

    qsort(list, 5, 8, (QfnCast)(strcmp));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) printf("%s\n", list[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "function pointer types are an exception to that guideline" Not really. Instead do `typedef int QfnCast (const void*, const void*);` ... `(QfnCast*)`. No hidden pointers behind typedef and as a bonus your syntax is now consistent with object pointers.

Comment: "you don't actually need that cast" You absolutely do, since conversions between incompatible function pointers is a constraint violation of simple assignment. It can never happen implicitly. As for the rationale behind the warning, it is there to tell you that your code is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin Your second point is indisputable, and I have removed that part of my answer. Your first point is a bit more 'style'-oriented. I appreciate your point of view, though.

Comment: Could you also explain why you need the parenthesis around the asterisk `(*)`

Comment: @user18989277 That's how C syntax for function pointers works: `int (*) (const void*, const void*)` specifies a pointer to a function returning an `int`. Without those brackets around the `*`, then `int * (const void*, const void*)` specifies a function returning a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: This explains the pointer conversion aspect of the question, but misses an even more relevant consideration: that the arguments to `strcmp()` have the wrong level of indirection for use with `qsort` to sort arrays of `char *` according to the data to which they each point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes. This point is covered, especially, in Lundin's answer. However, the example code I have given is the "rare use case" they mention (i.e. a true 2D array), in which each element of the array passed as the first argument to `qsort` is actually a block of data of the specified size (i.e. 8 bytes).

Answer (score 3):

`int (*)(const void*, const void*)` and `int (*)(const char*, const char*)` are not compatible function pointer types.

Casting between different, non-compatible function pointer types is explicitly undefined behavior, C17 6.3.2.3/8 emphasis mine:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
> type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.**

---

So if you cast `strcmp` to something else, you are explicitly invoking undefined behavior. It will likely work in practice on any system where all pointer types are of equal size. But if you are going to rely on that, you might as well cook up something like this:

```
typedef union
{
  int (*strcmp) (const char*, const char*);
  int (*compare)(const void*, const void*);
} strcmp_t;

const strcmp_t hack = { strcmp };
...
qsort(str, x, y, hack.compare);
```

This is just as undefined behavior (and as likely to work in practice) but more readable.

---

You can never do `qsort(str, x, y, strcmp)` because again `strcmp` is not compatible with the function pointer type expected by `qsort`. Function parameter passing is done as per assignment, so the rules of simple assignment are the relevant part, from C17 6.5.11:

> **Constratints**
> ...
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

Therefore `qsort(str, x, y, strcmp)` is always invalid C and this is not a quality of implementation issue. Rather, compilers letting this through without diagnostics are to be regarded as hopelessly broken.

---

And finally as noted in comments, `strcmp` only makes sense to use with `bsearch`/`qsort` in case you have a true 2D array of characters such as `char str[x][y];`. In my experience that's a rather rare use-case. When dealing with strings, you are far more likely to have `char* str[x]`, in which case you must write a wrapper around `strcmp` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with what you're trying to do.

First, `strcmp` has type `int (*)(const char *, const char *)`.  This type is incompatible with the type `int (*)(const void*, const void*)` expected by the function because the parameter types are not compatible.  This will result in `qsort` calling `strcmp` via an incompatible pointer type, and doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This *might* work if `char *` and `void *` have the same representation, but there's no guarantee this will be the case.

The second problem is that even if the call "works", what's ultimately being passed to `strcmp` isn't actually a `char *` but a `char **`.  This means that `strcmp` will be attempting to read a `char *` value as if it were a sequence of `char` values.

So you have to use a helper function to get the results you want:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **s1 = a;
    const char **s2 = b;
    return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}
```

Comment: Actually, there *is* a guarantee that `char *` and `void *` have the same representation. C17 6.2.5/28 says exactly that: "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type."  But that does not make the two function pointer types compatible, and does not change the fact that calling a function via a function pointer of incompatible type produces UB.

Answer (score 1):

as @some programmer dude has already stated, it depends on what you're sorting. If it's an array of strings, you can use `strcmp` without a helper function and do a cast to avoid ugly warnings:

```
char s_array[100][100] = { "z", "a", ... };

qsort( s_array, 100, 100, (int (*)(const void *, const void *))strcmp );
```

If it's an array of pointers you need a helper function because it gets passed pointers to pointers:

```
char *p_array[100] = { "z", "a", ... };

int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    return strcmp( *(const char **)p1, *(const char **)p2 );
}

qsort( p_array, 100, sizeof *p_array, cmp );
```